# How to remotely deploy actor with dynamic name in Akka.NET

Tags: c#, .net, akka, akka.net

When I look at the samples of the Akka.NET actor remote deployment, it is done via actor system configuration like this:

```
actor {
    provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
    deployment {
        /MyActor {
            remote = ""akka.tcp://MyActors@127.0.0.1:8091""
        }
    }
}
```

The string "MyActor" above is the actual actor name. It is not clear to me how would I deploy an actor that would have dynamic name (e.g. "MyActor:{UID}") or deploy unknown number of actors remotely? Is there a way to dynamically configure deployment options via code? It seems a bit tedious and very limited to specify all the remotely deployable actor names in the configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set deployment options using actor's Props like: `Props.Create(() => new MyActor).WithDeploy(new Deploy(new RemoteScope("akka.tcp://remote-system-name@ip:port/")))`.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that comes to my mind is to have one fixed name supervisor actor deployed remotely and use that one as a 'proxy' to create and possibly communicate with all the other dynamically named children actors.